# Mac Mini 2013 and Samsung UE32F4000 32 inches tv resolution problem

Tags: macos, resolution, hdmi, television

i'm trying to connect using hdmi cable my new mac mini and my new samsung 32 inches tv.

My problem is that i can't find the right configuration on mac and on tv to achive the correct resolution.

If i set from Preference Panel->Monitor->`Adapt to screen` ( Tv auto size resolution to 1366x768 @60Hz), the resolution is good but element inside the screen are very big as shown in the screenshot belove

[image]

If i set resolution to `scale`->1080p ( Tv auto size resolution to 1920x1
080 / 60p ), elements are with right dimension but everything is shown bad, as shown in image belove:
[image]

How can i solve in order to see dimension like in image 1 but resolution like image 1?

Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your TV has native resolution 1366x768 on 32", so it si normal it all looks big. This resolution is used on notebooks with 11-15" screens with elements size purposed for these small displays.

When you enforce full HD (1920x1080), your TV will recalculate received data from your computer (1920x1080) to native resolution (1366x768), so elements retain their size as for full HD, but look bad (they are not native, just calculated, reduced for less resolution).  Although it is not visible on your screenshot, but I believe that view is wrong.

Use smaller display with 1366x768, or native full HD display (will be still too big on 32", i think).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve this is to get a TV with 1920x1080 resolution.

What you are seeing in the top picture is the your Mac outputting to the native resolution of the TV - which is a resolution usually reserved for screens 11-13" in size.

What you are seeing in the image below is what happens when you show a 1920x1080 image scaled on a TV with only 1366x768 pixels.

To achieve the effect you desire, you need a TV with 1920x1080 pixels, and unfortunately that means getting a new TV.